How to generate optimized sources with and without sourcemaps for production use?
I'm trying to get my head around the usage of sourceMaps to resolve stack traces from production errors in angular.
I want to ship the optimized sources from dist/* generated by ng build --configuration=production obviously without the generated `.js.map files. At the same time I want to generate/use the `*.js.map` sources to resolve production stack traces.
However, I don't want to write a custom script to remove the `*.js.map` from the dist directory after the build is complete as this is error prone.
I thought I can do this in two steps:

Generate the production sources without the source maps. This is then shipped to production

If a production error occurs: generate the production chuncks again. This time including the source maps.


The problem that I'm now facing is that the generated .js have different hashes. I use "hidden": true to remove the sourceMappingUrl from the generated files. I would expect that the hidden field would prevent that the file contents / hashes changes. What am I missing?
https://angular.dev/reference/configs/workspace-config#source-map-configuration
Production Configuration for Production Compilation:
"production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": { 
                "scripts": false,
                "styles": false, 
                "hidden": true, 
                "vendor": false 
              },
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },

To generate the source maps I use the same configuration and only change the sourceMap configuration as follows:
              "sourceMap": { 
                "scripts": true,
                "styles": true, 
                "hidden": true, 
                "vendor": false 
              },

The generated output than differs, e.g.
59.10d4343a556f9106.js                | component-1-module           |   4.41 kB |                 1.61 kB
59.e2a4f51b3ab8de9e.js                | component-1-module           |   4.41 kB |                 1.63 kB
Using "@angular/cli": "^17.3.8",

Usually there is a replica environment, which has a clone of the production database, where you can run a build with sourceMaps enabled and view the changes.
The CI cannot know that production errors occurs, you can debug the issue from local pointing to production, or use kubernetes to hot swap a build with sourcemap enabled to production, debug it, and swap it back with no sourcemap version.
Either way this process cannot be automated, but it can be hotswapped using kuberenetes, so that production users do not experience any downtime.

I think you missunderstood my question. It's not about any CI / automation of this process.
I don't understand why the hashes of the generated output files from the ng build --configuration=production command is different when sourceMaps are enabled (via "sourceMap": {                  "scripts": true,                 "styles": true,                  "hidden": true,                  "vendor": false                },
vs. when they are not "script": false,  "styles": false, ...},

@oli0060 The hash generated is always unique per build run, you have to regenerate the build using "scripts": true so that the hash matches the sourcemap and the script tag in the index.html, it is done so that the application always uses the correct main.js file when deployed, gets rid of caching issues

The hash stays the same if I build without maiking any changes to the sources. With "hidden": true, as per angular documentation, the source map reference is not added to the output script files. I would expect to get the same hash since I haven't changed anything (source-wise) and the source map reference is not added to the output files.
